# How to join two arrayList in java?

Tags: java

I tried to assign one ArrayList to another by using:

```
ArrayList<type>list1 = this.reSetItemList() //this method return a arraylist
```

and

```
ArrayList<type>list1 = new ArrayList<>(this.reSetItemList());
```

and

```
ArrayList<type>list1.addAll(this.reSetItemList())
```

But all these three ways store nothing into list1. Could someone help me out? A lot of thanks!

Here is my code:

```
public calss Field{
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>(this.reSetItemList()); 

public ArrayList<Item> getItemList(){ //check if itemList is empty 
        return itemList;
    }

public ArrayList<Item> reSetItemList() { //initialize the field
    ArrayList<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for(int i = 0; i < this._area; i++) {
        arr.add(new Soil());
    }
    return arr;
}
public Field(int height, int width) {
        _height = height;
        _width = width;
        _area = _width * _height;

        for(int i = 1; i < field.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1 ; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                field[i][j] = itemList.get(i);
            }
        }
        
    }

mian: 
Field testField [2,2] = new Field;
print(testField.reSetItemList()) //will print".,.,.,."
print(testField.getItemList() //will print nothing
```

is that because I put the code in the wrong line?
[The full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnb9T.png)

Comment: I suggest posting more of the used code, since you're using the default constructor for example, and we don't know what it does and what's initialized how

Comment: This code is broken: `Field testField [2,2] = new Field;
print(testField.reSetItemList()`  "testField" is an array, and you don't access an array element when you call `print(testField.reSetItemList()`  I don't think this is what you are actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, the drive code is: `Field testField = new Field(5, 5);
  System.out.println(testField.reSetItemList());` and it will print 25 "."